# how to distinguish data types within xml?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, biztalk

**Is there a way to enforce that a certain value is a number rather than a string within an XML payload?**

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
<priority>1</priority>
</root>
```

When using several different libraries to convert this to json, the output I am getting is this:

```
{
   "priority": "1"
}
```

The output that I am expecting is:

```
{
   "priority": 1
}
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do we encode numbers within XML?**

Answer (score 1):

You can assign type to the XML element before assigning a value by declaring the following first in your XML:

`<xs:element name="priority" type="xs:decimal"/>`

Check out this link for other types other than decimal: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp

Comment: However, I'm not aware of XML-to-JSON conversion libraries that take this schema information into account. (Though this doesn't mean that such a library doesn't exist).

Comment: @MichaelKay It is taken into account in the BizTalk JSon Encoder.

Comment: However you will probably want to declare it as in int rather than a decimal.